Understanding some statement in proof of Chapter 8, Theorem 5.11 of Ideals, varieties, and algoritms ( reductibility to case of affine varieites )
I am reading the Cavid A.Cox, John Little, Donal O'Shea's Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, Fourth Edition, Chapter 8, Theorem 5.11 ( p. 433 ) and stuck at understanding some statement.

Theorem 11. Let $k$ be algebraically closed and let $F : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ be defined by homogeneous polynomials $f_0, \dots, f_m \in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ which have the same total degree $>0$ and no common zeros in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ; i.e., $F( x_0 : \cdots : x_n) := (f_0(x_0,\dots, x_n)  : \cdots : f_m(x_0, \dots , x_n))$ ( well-defined ). In $k[x_0,\dots, x_n , y_0 , \dots, y_m]$, let $I$ be the ideal $\langle y_0 -f_0 , \dots , y_m -f_m \rangle$and let $I_{n+1} := I \cap k[y_0,\dots, y_m]$ be the $n+1$-th elimination ideal. Then $I_{n+1}$ is a homogeneous ideal in $k[y_0,\dots, y_m]$, and $$ F(\mathbb{P}^n)=V(I_{n+1}).$$

It's proof consists of three steps. First he proves that $I_{n+1}$ is a homogeneous ideal. Second,   in the fifth paragraph of the proof, he define $J : = \langle y_if_j- y_j f_i \rangle$  ( bihomogeneous ideal - defined in his book p.433~434 ) and show in sixth paragraph that $F(\mathbb{P}^n) = V(\hat{J})$, where $\hat{J} := ( J : \langle x_0 , \dots, x_n \rangle^{\infty} ) \cap k[y_1 ,\dots, y_m]$ is its projective elimination ideal ( his book p.425 ).
Third, he shows that $V(\hat{J}) = V(I_{n+1})$ which is desired. And in showing this third part, he wrotes in seventh paragraph that  "to show  that $V(\hat{J}) = V(I_{n+1})$ in $\mathbb{P}^m$, is suffices to work in affine space $k^{m+1}$ and prove that $V_{a}(\hat{J}) = V_{a}(I_{n+1})$" ( affine versions of variety ). I don't understand this statement. How can we reduce to the affine case ? I found associated Proposition ( his book p.399 )  :

Proposition 6. Let $V= V(f_1, \dots, f_s)$ be a projective variety. Then $W:=V \cap U_0$ can be identified with the affine variety $V(g_1, \dots, g_s ) \subseteq k^n$, where $g_i ( x_1, \dots, x_n) : = f_{i}(1,x_1, \dots , x_n)$ for each $1 \le i \le s$. Here, $U_0 := \{ ( x_0  : \cdots : x_n ) \in \mathbb{P}^n(k) | x_0 \neq 0 \}$.

Could we try to use the proposition, by using covering $\mathbb{P}^n(k)=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n}U_i$ ?  Can anyone help?

Here is an attempt, although I haven't fully studied this portion of the text. Suppose that $\mathbf{V}_a(\hat{J}) = \mathbf{V}_a(I_{n + 1})$. So using some tools found in the proof of Theorem 9 Chapter 8 $\S 3$, you should be able to use the fact that $\mathbf{I}_a(\mathbf{V}_a(\hat{J})) = \mathbf{I}_a(\mathbf{V}_a(I_{n + 1}))$ to show that $\mathbf{V}(\hat{J}) = \mathbf{V}(I_{n + 1})$.

Thanks! To apply the proof of Theorem 9, Chapter 8,  $\S 3$, we need that $\hat{J}$, $I_{n+1}$ are homogeneous and $V(\hat{J})$, $V(I_{n+1})$ are nonempty. The  homogeneity of $\hat{J}$, $I_{n+1}$  are proved in the proof of the theroem 11 in the question. And since $F(\mathbb{P}^n) = V(\hat{J})$ as in the question, $V(\hat{J})$ is nonempty. And can we show that $V(I_{n+1})$ is also nonempty? How?

My elimination theory is rusty but my understanding is that if $\mathbf{V}(I_{n + 1})$ was empty then $\mathbf{V}(I)$ would be empty and then we don't have anything to show?

Why the emptiness of $V(I)$ leads to situation that we don’t have anything to show?

Actually I don't think $\mathbf{V}(I)$ as defined can be empty in the first place as it contains the set ${ [x_0 \colon \cdots \colon x_n \colon f_0(\overline{x}) \colon \cdots \colon f_m(\overline{x})] \ |\ x \in \mathbb{P}^n}$ which is nonempty right?

Yeah~  It’s O.K. Thanks.
